# Get real file path from URI on Android 10 , Also content URI is suffixed with msf:documentid in Android 10

Tags: android, xamarin

I was trying to get the real path from intent chooser in Xamarin Android and its working fine in every android version except android 10 . In android 10 content uri comes like

**content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A180**

Comment: If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Nouf try this library [PickIt](https://github.com/HBiSoft/PickiT)

Answer (score 1):

Android 10 has scoped storage enabled by default. This means you cannot directly get access to the external storage path - take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#raw-file-paths).

You can do what is suggested by setting [requestLegacyExternalStorage](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/R.attr#requestLegacyExternalStorage:kotlin.Int) to `true` in your app's AndroidManifest.xml, but keep in mind this will only work for targetSdk 29 and not for 30+.

If you're trying to access media, this should be done through the [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore).
Otherwise, take a look at the [scoped storage docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage).

Comment: I wonder what this all has to do with the posted problem.

Comment: @blackapps As the document id in the content uri comes as msf:89 hence I am not able ti get the real path of the file. Once I get the real path this I have to send to a third party chat cloud so they will get the file and store it in their cloud .

Comment: Sorry, but my comment here was not for you of course. But there is one for you somewhere else. Please react there by editing your post.

Comment: @blackapps As I explained in the very first paragraph, you cannot get access to the external storage path since Android 10. I also provided a temporary workaround (the manifest flag) as well as the proper way to implement accessing media via MediaStore and the link to relevant docs. I don't understand what you found unclear or irrelevant.

Comment: How to get access to external storage was not the question of original poster. OP only wanted to get a path for an uri. Please reread.

Comment: Reread my last comment - access to the external storage PATH. and just as you cannot get access to the storage, you cannot get access to the path either because it is from external storage.

Answer (score 1):

after getting the URI of the image file of course we need to edit this file by compressing it, after that getting a real file path.if you targeting SDK 30, this is my implementation using scoped storage ;)
don't forget to upvoting my answer.

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.ImageDecoder
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.provider.MediaStore
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.io.FileOutputStream


/**
* Created by Mostafa Anter on 11/5/20.
*/

object PhotoHelper{

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        /**
         * mContext: context from activity or fragment,
         * imageSelectedUri: uri that return from any pick picture library it usually return inside on activity response method
         * appFolderName: name of folder that will generate to save compressing images ;)
         * createdImageCompressedName : random name of new compressed image 
         */
fun compressGetImageFilePath(
        mContext: Context,
        imageSelectedUri: Uri,
        appFolderName: String,
        createdImageCompressedName: String = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
): String {
    //region Getting the photo to process it
    val bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(mContext.contentResolver, imageSelectedUri))
    } else {
        mContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(imageSelectedUri)?.use { inputStream ->
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
        }
    }
    // endregion

    //region save photo to gallery using Scoped storage
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, createdImageCompressedName)
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/$appFolderName/")
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
    }

    val collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    val imageUri = mContext.contentResolver.insert(collection, values)
    //endregion


    //region save image
    mContext.contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri!!).use { out ->
        bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)
    }

    values.clear()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
    mContext.contentResolver.update(imageUri, values, null, null)
    //endregion


    //region get file path of content uri
    val file = File(mContext.cacheDir, "$createdImageCompressedName.png")
    try {
        val assetFileDescriptor: AssetFileDescriptor = mContext.contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(imageUri, "r")!!

        val inputStream = FileInputStream(assetFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)

        inputStream.close()
        outputStream.close()


    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    //endregion



    return file.path

    }
}
```

so easy if you want to target old and new devices simply make if statement to check android version if greater or equal android Q use my method else use your old method.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the fileName, and then build the path.

- Query the file name:

  ```
    public static string getFileName(Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        ICursor cursor = null;
        string[] projection = {
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName
        };

        try
        {
            cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                int index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName);
                return cursor.GetString(index);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cursor != null)
                if (cursor != null)
                {
                    cursor.Close();
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
  ```

Build the path:

```
string fileName = getFileName(context, uri);
string filePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/Download/" + fileName;
```